# Which widget in flutter can I use to scroll the screen up on click of down arrow?

Tags: android, flutter

Couldn't find the screenshots to show. I want to know which widget can I use for the following functionality.

A full size screen with no appbar or bottom bar. A full screen video is playing with its title and 2 lines description in the bottom and lastly, a down faces arrow in the center.
On click of this arrow, the screen goes up, the video takes up a small screen, the complete description becomes visible and other things become visible as screen becomes scrollable.
Please help me find the widget that I can use here.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one widget to do everything you mentioned above. You will have to code it yourself. In order to scroll the screen up you should use a `ScrollController` and attach it to your `ListView` and call `animateTo`.